# ListView fill in RelativePanel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am to create a HamburgerMenu like Win10 apps. The HamburgerMenu base is the `SplitView` component and to distribute the children in SplitView I chose to use a RelativePanel, so I can choose which menu items will be on the top and which ones will be on the bottom, like Weather App.

[image]

However, in my app the bottom items do not have the same width as the top items.

[image]

I've tried several things, `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`, binding between the top `LitView` and bottom `ListView`, but nothing changes.
The bottom `ListView` ignores any non-manual (non-fixed) width setting.
Below is my XAML code.

```
<Grid x:Name="GridToMainPage">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RelativePanel x:Name="RelatMainPanelTop" Background="#FFFF6800">

            <Button x:Name="HamburgerMenuButton" Content="&#xE700;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFFF6800" Height="39.5" Width="{Binding CompactPaneLength, ElementName=MainSplitView}" Click="OnHaburgerButtonClick"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="NavigationTitle" Text="Início" RelativePanel.RightOf="HamburgerMenuButton" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="MainSearchTextBox" Width="200" PlaceholderText="Buscar" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.LeftOf="MainSearchButtom"/>
            <Button x:Name="MainSearchButtom" Content="&#xE1A3;" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

        </RelativePanel>

        <SplitView x:Name="MainSplitView" Grid.Row="1" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" CompactPaneLength="43" OpenPaneLength="{Binding Width, ElementName=HamburgerMenuListView1}">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <RelativePanel x:Name="MainSplitRelativPanel">

                    <ListView x:Name="HamburgerMenuListView1">
                        <ListViewItem x:Name="HomeSplittem">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="HomeStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="HomeIconSplitItem" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE80F;" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="HomeTextSplitItem" FontSize="18" Text="Início" Margin="12.5,0,0,0" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                        <ListViewItem x:Name="PersonsSplitItem">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="PersonsStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PersonsIconSplitItem" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE716;" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PersonsTextSplitItem" FontSize="18" Text="Pessoas" Margin="12.5,0,0,0" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                        <ListViewItem x:Name="MediaSplitItem">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="MediaStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MediaIconSplitItem" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE8F1;" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MediaTextSplitItem" FontSize="18" Text="Mídias" Margin="12.5,0,0,0" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                        <ListViewItem x:Name="MovementsSplitItem">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="MovementsStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MovementsIconSplitItem" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE7BF;" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MovementsTextSplitItem" FontSize="18" Text="Movimentações" Margin="12.5,0,0,0" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                        <ListViewItem x:Name="CashDeskSplitItem">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="CashDeskStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="CashDeskIconSplitItem" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE75F;" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="CashDeskTextSplitItem" FontSize="18" Text="Caixa" Margin="12.5,0,0,0" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                        <ListViewItem x:Name="ReportsSplitItem">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="ReportsStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ReportsIconSplitItem" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" Text="&#xEB05;" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ReportsTextSplitItem" FontSize="18" Text="Relatórios" Margin="12.5,0,0,0" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFFF6800"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                        <ListViewItem x:Name="ConfigSplitItem">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="ConfigStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ConfigIconSplitItem" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE90F;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ConfiTextSplitItem" FontSize="18" Text="Configurações" Margin="12.5,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>

                    </ListView>

                    <ListView x:Name="HambugerMenuListView2" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,20" Width="181">
                        <ListViewItem x:Name="LoginSplitItem" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="LoginStackPanelViewItem" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="LoginIconSplitItem" FontSize="18" Text="&#xE8D7;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="LoginTextSplitItem" FontSize="18" Text="User Name" Margin="12.5,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListViewItem>
                    </ListView>

                </RelativePanel>
            </SplitView.Pane>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's a much simpler way to achieve what you want.

You kinda did it with this line of code -

```
OpenPaneLength="{Binding Width, ElementName=HamburgerMenuListView1}"
```

Since you haven't actually specified the `Wdith` of `HamburgerMenuListView1`, the `Width` will always be `double.NaN`. This is basically equivalent to this -

```
OpenPaneLength="Auto"
```

The default value of `OpenPaneLength` is `320`, since you have set it to `Auto`, the width of the side panel will basically be stretched based on the max width of its children.

Your first `ListView` is clearly wider so the parent side panel will stretch to its width; your second `ListView` is shorter, and since its default horizontal alignment (inside a `RelativePanel`) is `Left`, you will see it's left-aligned as shown on your screenshot.

So, the real question is, how to stretch the second `ListView` to fit the whole side panel?

All you need is to add these two lines to the second `ListView` -

```
RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
```

Personally, I would prefer to leave the `OpenPaneLength` unchanged 'cause by doing this, to me it looks a bit weird as there's not enough *gap* between the items and the edges of the side panel. Or maybe simply reduce it a little bit to achieve the best visual result.

Comment: Instead of the 'Width' (which will be `doubleNaN` as you said), he could use `ActualWidth` property instead.

Comment: @GeorgeChond, no, `ActualWidth` doesn't update the binding.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/321b52ed-57be-4505-adcd-922a71e3b181/listview-fill-in-relativepanel?forum=wpdevelop).
In practice it implements in code-behind something that should work through XAML Bindings.
The reason for not working is unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason for not working is unknown to me.

It is because the ActualWidth does not raise property change notifications and should be thought of as a regular CLR property and not a dependency property as stated in the documentation on MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx

Since the ActualWidth of the ListView in the Pane doesn't get updated you could set the Width programmatically instead of using a binding:

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="MainSplitRelativPanel" SizeChanged="MainSplitRelativPanel_SizeChanged">
 ...
</RelativePanel>
```

---

```
private void MainSplitRelativPanel_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    HambugerMenuListView2.Width = HamburgerMenuListView1.ActualWidth;
}
```